# How to count the total number of results before a hyphen?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sequelpro

I am looking to count the number of results from a SQL count query, the results currently have like 50 results, but in reality there are only 5 results... the results appear in a format such as:

```
test1-helpme1
test1-helpme3
test1-helpme4
test2-helpme1
test2-helpme2
test3-helpme4
```

Is there a way I can count just the "testx-" part of the results?
There can be hundreds of results so the number part of "test" can't be hardcoded

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as CountbyID, OriginalId FROM Table1 GROUP BY OriginalId;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the number of the distinct occurrences of the pattern, then:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(OriginalId, INSTR(OriginalId, '-') - 1)) as counter
FROM Table1
```

or a counter for each one:

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(OriginalId, INSTR(OriginalId, '-') - 1) pattern,
  COUNT(*) as counter
FROM Table1
GROUP BY LEFT(OriginalId, INSTR(OriginalId, '-') - 1)
```

Comment: Could you explain what is going on in this SQL? This is exactly what i need!

Comment: This: `LEFT(OriginalId, INSTR(OriginalId, '-') - 1))` gives the part up to the `-`. Then the 1st query counts how many distinct of them exist in the table. The 2nd groups the table by that and counts how many items exist in each group.

Answer (score 0):

Yup you can use LEFT to group by a subset of the string:

```
declare @test as table (test varchar(100))

insert into @test
Select 'test1-helpme1' UNION ALL
Select 'test1-helpme3' UNION ALL
Select 'test1-helpme4' UNION ALL
Select 'test2-helpme1' UNION ALL
Select 'test2-helpme4'

Select count(*) as countbyID, left(test,5) as originalid from @test group by left(test,5)
```